# match list of items with a phrase to isolate a word

Tags: python

I have a library of colors in a text file and I want to isolate the color word in a phrase.

```
color.txt  = ["red" , " green" , "blue"]

line1 = 'the car is blue'
```

Comment: What do you mean by a library of colors?

Comment: `[word for word in line1.split() if word in color.txt]`

Comment: Is the 'color.txt' a variable or a text file? @alaniwi

Comment: Or you could do something like `set(line1.split()).intersection(set(color.txt))`. This will produce a set. You haven't said exactly what the output should consist of.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I was just going by the code that is written and assuming it was indeed a variable, but yes, you're probably right, maybe they don't have an object called `color` with property `txt`.

Comment: This is not code, this is a code request.

Comment: Yes @alaniwi very poorly worded post!

Comment: @alaniwi Basically I am trying to make a program that looks for colors. Once it finds the color I just want to print out the color. Sorry first time posting.

Comment: Please improve your question quality.

Answer (score 0):

this code will print the color available in the color.txt file

```
f = open("color.txt", "r")
color = f.read() #Read file
color = eval(color) #convert file content to list
line1 = 'the car is blue'
for _ in color: #Search function
    if line1.find(str(_),0) != -1:
        print(_, " is in the file")
```